# HBase giving "JAVA_HOME is not set" while running

Tags: java, hbase

I am using MacOS `Sierra version 10.12.4` and using `zsh shell`. I have installed [HBase version 1.2.6](https://archive.apache.org/dist/hbase/1.2.6/hbase-1.2.6-bin.tar.gz) and trying to run it. I have pre-installed `JAVA JDK version 1.8.0_131`.

I have set up the `$JAVA_HOME` path in `~.bash_profile` and `~.zshrc` and also in `hbase-1.2.6/conf/hbase-env.sh` file. So when I run the following commands, it shows this

```
 ❯ echo $JAVA_HOME                                                                                                                                                        

 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/

❯ $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version                                                                                                                                           [16:55:16]
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

But, when I run the following commands inside the folder `hbase-1.2.6`
 to run the HBase, it gives me `JAVA_HOME is not set error`.

```
 ❯ sudo bin/start-hbase.sh                                                                                                                                            

Password:
+======================================================================+
|                    Error: JAVA_HOME is not set                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Please download the latest Sun JDK from the Sun Java web site        |
|     > http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads        |
|                                                                      |
| HBase requires Java 1.7 or later.                                    |
+======================================================================+


❯ sudo bin/hbase shell                                                                                                                                                   [16:58:36]
+======================================================================+
|                    Error: JAVA_HOME is not set                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Please download the latest Sun JDK from the Sun Java web site        |
|     > http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads        |
|                                                                      |
| HBase requires Java 1.7 or later.                                    |
+======================================================================+                           |
```

I am able to run it at the user level without using `sudo`. How can I run at the sudo level?

Comment: just go inside the folder Hbse and set Java_Home manually. 
**export $JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/**

Answer (score 1):

```
Step 1: Search JAVA_HOME in  hbase-env.sh 
Step 2: Comment out # from JAVA_HOME line and edit the JAVA_HOME directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jd‌​k/Contents/Home/
```

before running `HBase` inside the `HBase` diretory. And also check that `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to correct directory in Linux.